# How to get the name of a course's teacher

Tags: mysql, moodle

Could you help me create a query that shows the teacher(s) of a course

Example:

Title of course: Course 1
Teacher: James Anderson

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ldm_user.id,
ldm_user.firstname, 
ldm_user.lastname,
ldm_course.shortname,
ldm_course.fullname,
ldm_role.id as role_id, 
ldm_role_assignments.id

FROM ldm_course,ldm_user,ldm_role,ldm_context,ldm_role_assignments

WHERE ldm_course.fullname = "i-ONS001 Taller de Lectura y Redacción IV" and ldm_role_assignments.id = 4
```

But this is not returning the name of the teacher as expected.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide table structure and also it would be great if you can create some SQL Fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little old, but I had to spend some time trying to figure it out and thought I would share what I came up with.

The basic PHP below will get the list of users enrolled in the course, comb through them and find any with the "editingteacher" role.

```
    $moodle_site = 'YOUR_MOODLE_URL';
    $moodle_token = 'YOUR_MOODLE_TOKEN';
    $courseid = 7; // Enter the Moodle course ID you want to find the teacher for
    
    $restformat = 'json';
    $params = '';
    $functionname = 'core_enrol_get_enrolled_users'; // Make sure function is enabled in Moodle
    $serverurl = $moodle_site . '/webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . $moodle_token . '&wsfunction=' . $functionname . '&courseid='.$courseid;
    $curl = new curl;
    $restformat = ($restformat == 'json') ? '&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat : '';
    $resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
    $get_result = json_decode($resp, true);

    if (!empty($resp)) {
        foreach ($get_result as $array_level1) {
            foreach ($array_level1["roles"] as $array_level2) {
                if ($array_level2["shortname"]=='editingteacher') {
                    echo 'Teacher ID: '.$array_level1["id"].'<br>';
                    echo 'Teacher Name: '.$array_level1["firstname"].' '.$array_level1["lastname"].'<br>';
                    echo 'Teacher Email: '.$array_level1["email"].'<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No users were returned.<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete, because the exact query will vary depending on your version of Moodle, whether you're using SQL or MySQL, and also we can't give you a comprehensive answer without knowing your table structures.

*However*, in Moodle 2.x you can use an API query (PHP) which looks something like this:

```
$role = $DB->get_record('role', array('shortname' => 'editingteacher'));
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid);
$teachers = get_role_users($role->id, $context);
```

and then doing a `return $teachers;` or `echo $teachers;` to output said results.

Like I said, without knowing your exact system details I can't give you an accurate response and a functioning query so take that with a pinch of salt; you might need to play around with it to get it to work.

> Ref: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=115636

Comment: Sorry for that friend... I'm using moodle 2.7 and i pretend the next...

In the fronpage i have the avaible courses, when i click it in one course i need to get the name course and the teacher...

Comment: In this post i explain my problem, this page can't post image...

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=316627#p1268867